# Get month with 30 days

Tags: java, date

> April, June, September and November
>
> have 30 days.

I want the month that consists of 30 days to perform some
logic in java.

Comment: What do you mean by "the month that consists of 30 days"? As you've said, there are multiple months. Your post is far too vague to answer.

Comment: it seems you haven't tried anything by yourself

Comment: you already have them ? Why generate each time ?

Comment: All months have 30 days, except Feb

Answer (score 1):

No matter how many days the month have check your month is here or not like

```
 public boolean isMyMonth(int month)
    {

        return ((month == Calendar.APRIL) || 
                (month == Calendar.JUNE) || 
                (month == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) ||
                (month == Calendar.NOVEMBER) || );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to all.I worked it out using datejs.